# Creating a domain instance with a hibernate event from BootStrap.groovy

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, bootstrapping

I am attempting to create a User domain object in my BootStrap.groovy file but receive the following error:

```
[ERROR]:AssertionFailure  an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)
```

The domain object is shown below: the problem occurs when calling a service from within the afterInsert method. The service is non-null and invoking any method on it, including toString() or inspect(), seems to cause the error.

**BootStrap.groovy**

```
def newUser = new User(...)
newUser.save(flush:true, failOnError: true)
```

**User.groovy**

```
class User extends Auth {
    transient def userService

    ...

    def afterInsert() {
        log.debug "SERVICE: ${userService == null ? 'NULL': 'NOT NULL'}" // Gives: SERVICE: NOT NULL

        // Either of the following lines cause the error when uncommented
        //log.debug "SERVICE: ${userService.toString()}"
        //userService?.makeUser(this)
    }

}
```

Should this be possible using BootStrap or do I have something fundamentally wrong?

Alternatively, is it possible to ignore this code when called from BootStrap? E.g. Something similar to:

```
def afterInsert() {
    if (notBootStrap()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Any input will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Service` needs a `transaction`.

```
def afterInsert() {
        User.withTransaction{
           userService.makeUser(this)
        }
    }
```